# Differences of maven JSF api artifacts

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, maven

Do you know guys the differences between the following artifacts?
Which one should I use in which circumstances?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Or more specifically I am planning to replace the 1st dependency with 2nd one for my webapp which will deploy to both JBoss 7.1.1 and Glassfish 3.1.2.1. Should I expect any side effects?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is provided by jboss.org and the second one is Developed through the Java Community Process under [JSR - 314](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314).You can replace 1st dependency with 2nd one. There is no side effects.